# Setting up Apache as fallback for webapplication server on Centos

Tags: apache-2.4, port, centos7

I run a web application server (namely, eXist db) which listens to port 8080. Unfortunately, eXist is not totally reliable. Therefore, I'd like to set up Apache 2.4 as a fallback web server: Whenever exist-db is down, any HTTP request to port 8080 should be responded by Apache. Other than that, Apache should not respond to any HTTP request. However, I have no idea on how to do that and thus, appreciate any help.

The machine runs with Centos 7.

Answer (score 1):

No.
What you *should* do, is configure Apache to listen on port 80, and reverse proxy connections to eXist db.

You will need to enable the following apache modules:

```
proxy proxy_ajp proxy_http rewrite deflate headers proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_html

a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_ajp
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod deflate
a2enmod headers
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_html
```

Then in your VirtualHost config:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
ServerName existdb.blah
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache, and connect to http://your.apache:80/ and you should see the eXist DB page.

You could also optionally enable caching for reverse proxied connections, but this may lead to you getting stale data.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get a 503 Service Unavailable error when connecting to localhost:80 (which does work without setting the Virtual Host as you suggested). Maybe I have to define the eXist ServerName somewhere?

Comment: After some trouble with SELinux, it works now that by calling localhost:80 -- I now see the eXist DB page. However, once I shut down eXist, I get again a "503 Service Unavailable" error, which is not what I want. In case eXist is unreachable, index.html file in Apache's root should be displayed.

Comment: Why? If the database is unavailable, the last thing you want is to return HTTP 200 OK (because it's very obviously not OK.)  You could customise the page it shows for 503, but you really really want to keep the fact that it's not OK.

Comment: Well, for most users it won't make a huge difference whether the database works or not. This is why, there is no need to make them know that something in the back end went wrong. The HTML fallback page is sufficient. But customizing the error page is what I did now. Thanks!